# How to add a UIElement to a ContainerVisual?

Tags: wpf

I'm developing a custom `DocumentPaginator` that allows a caller to specify its own header content, which it does by providing a UIElement - which could be a company logo (Image), heading text (TextBlock), or whatever.

I'm creating the header like this, where `CustomHeaderContent` is the header content provided by the caller:-

```
var header = new ContainerVisual();
header.Transform = new TranslateTransform(_margin.Width, _margin.Height);  
// Add the caller's content (CustomHeaderContent is of type UIElement)
header.Children.Add(CustomHeaderContent);
```

(This `header` ContainerVisual eventually gets added to another ContainerVisual  representing the entire printed page).

For now, my caller just programmatically creates a `Border` and assigns this to the `CustomHeaderContent` property:-

```
_docPaginator.CustomHeaderContent = new Border { Background = ... };
```

However when I run the application it fails on the `header.Children.Add(...);` line with the exception:-

> Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

How can I add a UIElement to a ContainerVisual - if it's even possible? If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: Please also show the code where CustomHeaderContent is created.

Comment: @Clemens it's nothing special, but I have updated the question.

Comment: Is CustomHeaderContent used anywhere else, e.g. in XAML? It seems to be already part of a visual tree.

Comment: @Clemens no it's created just as you see it above, and not used elsewhere. I assumed the issue related to the second half of the exception ("...or the root of a CompositionTarget"), whatever that means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting nowhere fast, so I've now refactored the code to use delegates where the caller can "draw" the header and footer content. Something like this:-

```
public delegate void DrawHeaderDelegate(DrawingContext ctx, Rect bounds);

public DrawHeaderDelegate DrawCustomHeader { get; set; }

// Code within the GetPage() method now looks like:-
    var header = new DrawingVisual();
    header.Transform = new TranslateTransform(_margin.Width, _margin.Height);
    using (var ctx = header.RenderOpen())
    {
       var bounds = new Rect(0, 0, UsablePageWidth, HeaderHeight);
       DrawCustomHeader(ctx, bounds); // Call the delegate
    }
```

Then in the caller:-

```
_docPaginator.DrawCustomHeader = (ctx, bounds) =>
   {
      ctx.DrawText ... // Or whatever
   };
```